# Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode. nvidia driver gforce 4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

Whenever I start up my computer I get this message: 
Ubuntu is running in low-graphics mode. 
(EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module!
Please ensure
(EE) NVIDIA(0): that there is a supported NVIDIA GPU in this system, and
(EE) NVIDIA(0): that the NVIDIA device files have been created properly
.
.
.
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
Then I press "ok" and start my session (seems like the only way to get to gui) through low-graphics mode.
But the thing is the resolution is fine. How do I just prevent the message from showing up?
It's gotten quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1000076.html):

> Just re-run the installer file the
>   original way you did it, clicking yes
>   to all the defaults. the module will
>   be re-compiled, and a quick sudo
>   /etc/init.d/gdm start will have you
>   back in gnome.